# Error al publicar en Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net

Hasta el día de hoy no había tenido este problema al publicar en **visual studio** **2019.** estoy tratando de publicar un proyecto web en **.NET Framework4.6.2** y el error que me da es el siguiente:

> Error      No se pudo ejecutar la tarea ejecutable especificada "sgen.exe". System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): El nombre del archivo o la extensión es demasiado largo
>      en System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
>      en System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
>      en Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)
>      en Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()  BizInside Base MultiLogIn               Compilación

El problema que veo, es que no se cual archivo es el problematico para intentar acortarlo.

Cualquier ayuda se agradece mucho!

Comment: Si sabes mas o menos donde se generan los archivos podrias poner un punto de Debug

Comment: El problema no me lo da al ejecutar el proyecto, en verdad, me funciona todo bien al ejecutarlo y usarlo desde visual Studio, el problema es al intentar publicarlo, ya sea en carpeta local, en Azure o por FTP con un perfil de publicación estas dos ultimas.

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta te fue de utilidad?

Comment: El problema que tengo es que al publicar en el servidor ftp no actualiza todos los cambios realizados en desarrollo local, he probado muchísimas opciones como eliminar lo publicado anterior o no optimizar códigos de los proyectos, limpiar, recompilar solución y proyectos y sigue igual.
Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias a todos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parte del error dice:

> El nombre del archivo o la extensión es demasiado largo

Por lo tanto, intenta mover el proyecto a una carpeta de nombre corto como `C:\Dev\TuProyectoAqui`

Comment: Efectivamente, he realizado esto y me ha publicado bien en Azure, me sigue dando rabia no saber que archivo es el que da problemas, pero vigilare para acortar las rutas de los archivos.

Comment: Descuida, así sucede en la programación, por eso, conforme pase el tiempo, conocerás más desarrolladores que tienen la carpeta de desarrollo como `C:\Dev`

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, según el código de error de Visual Studio dice que no tiene acceso a la aplicación por algún motivo:

1. El archivo no existe.
2. No tienes acceso a él.

Y dado tu código `Process.Start()` creo que el lugar desde donde quieres iniciar esa aplicación o archivo no debe tener los permisos necesarios. Lo mas seguro es que sea un archivo que requiera permisos de administración, por lo que deberías iniciar con la cuenta de administración en tu app.

[image: Donde cambiar permisos]

Recuerda que si la respuesta te ayudó, debes marcarla y ante todas las dudas que tengas, no olvides preguntar.